# Trying to dismiss presentingViewController using button in the subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Basically I have two xibs, the first one is the main `xib` that contains a button that triggers an `IBAction` that calls:

```
UIViewController *overlaywindow = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewInvenView" bundle:nil];
overlaywindow.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
overlaywindow.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:overlaywindow animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This produces the result I want.

However, in `NewInvenView.xib` I'm trying to create a button that will dismiss itself (and close the PresentingView). I link the button with the NewInvenViewController.h and implements the method in NewInvenViewController.m. But when I run it, it doesn't work.

Whenever the button is triggered, the function is called but I get an error:

> 2012-12-24 20:33:50.984 Dokodemo[1467:907] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController filterstock:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x21033990'...

I think it's also important to note that, I get an error regardless of what is inside the function implementation. Even when the function does nothing

why is this?

Comment: The class having filterstock function is released, due to this you are getting this crash. Check your allocation of same class. Hope it helps you..

Comment: look the places where filterstock: method is called, there is your problem; maybe you wrongly connected IBAction

Comment: filterstock is empty. I'm pretty sure I connected everything correctly though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Do the flip Animation with  navigationController it will be Easy.

```
 -(void)goToNextView:(id)sender{

          NextView *info3 = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:info3];

            info3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];

        }
```

// if you using latest Version of iOS Just Change the following

`[self.navigationController presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];`

in your Second view Controller You can use this to Dismiss.

```
-(IBAction)goToPrevious:(id)sender

{

[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// For latest Version

// [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: presentModalViewController is deprecated, it says.

Comment: Yes if you using latest Version of ios Just Change the following :

 `[self presentViewController:nvc
                           animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is related to the nib file. If you check the error message, it says `-[UIViewController filterstock:]:`, which means that the message is sent to an object of `UIViewController` not `NewInvenViewController`.

Make sure that you set the class properly from the nib file, from the inspector pane.